# RecursiveASMVisitor and Finding Function Call Sites

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there a way to find the call sites of a `FunctionDecl` inside a `VisitFunctionDecl` inside a `RecursiveASTVisitor`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `RecursiveASTVisitor` to find a `CallExpr` whose callee is the `FunctionDecl` you're looking for. Clang actually has a special interface for type of thing called the [matcher interface](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html), which you can experiment with using the command-line tool "clang-query":

```
   $ clang-query-7 ast.cpp --
   clang-query> m callExpr(callee(functionDecl(hasName("somefunc"))))

   Match #1:

   /home/nicholas/ast.cpp:4:3: note: "root" binds here
     somefunc(1 + somefunc(0));
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

   Match #2:

   /home/nicholas/ast.cpp:4:16: note: "root" binds here
     somefunc(1 + somefunc(0));
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
   2 matches.
```

The match expression that you write in this tool (which features tab completion!) is valid C++ using the clang AST matcher library. Once you've iterated on the expression and are confident that it works, just copy and paste it into your project.